# match query returns exact values only in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have following documents:

```
    {
        "_index": "testrest",
        "_type": "testrest",
        "_id": "sadfasdfw1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {,
            "s_item_name": "Create",
            "request_id": "35",
            "confidence": "0.5",
        }
    },
    {
        "_index": "testrest",
        "_type": "testrest",
        "_id": "asdfds",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {,
            "s_item_name": "Update",
            "request_id": "35",
            "confidence": "0.3333",
        }
    },
```

I am trying to get results for `request_id` of `35` and their confidence values.

For eg. if input is only `0.` then both results should be displayed.

And if input is `0.5` then only first doc., and if `0.3` only second doc.

Here's what I tried:

```
 {
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "must": [ 
        { "match":  { "confidence_score": "0.33" }}
      ],
      "filter": {
        "term": {
            "request_id": "35"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This gives `0` results. Since it requires exact values only, like `0.5` or `0.3333`.

I thought `match` works for this instead of `term`.

How do I make the query similar to `LIKE` operator in `SQL`?

Comment: What field type have you chosen for the `confidence` field? it should be a float or double, but not text

Comment: all fields are `text`.

Comment: You should definitely make them `float` or `double`, it rarely makes sense to search numbers with full-text search queries

Comment: have you tried wild card query?

Comment: @AbdullahAhsan yes.. it's getting me the same.. I'll make another post on that.

Comment: @azima try SQL query using X-PACK.

Answer (score 0):

For like I should suggest you have a look at `wildcard, prefix or match_phrase` type in elastic search or if you are using the latest version you can write SQL statement using ES plugin.